# Apache Flink (How to uniquely tag Jobs)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible to tag jobs with a unique name so I can stop them at a later date?.  I don't really want to grep and persist Job IDs.

In a nutshell I want to stop a job as part of my deployment and deploy the new one.

Answer (score 6):

You can name jobs when you start them in the `execute(name: String)` call, e.g.,

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()

val result: DataStream[] = ???       // your job logic
result.addSink(new YourSinkFunction) // add a sink

env.execute("Name of your job")      // execute and assign a name
```

The [REST API of the JobManager](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/internals/monitoring_rest_api.html#overview-of-jobs) provides a list of job details which include the name of the job and its JobId.

Comment: Can I stop the job using this name?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You need the JobId for that.

Comment: Is there any best practices for tracking jobs and updating existing jobs?.  At the moment in order to support updates to existing jobs, I have to persist the jobIds somewhere for reference.

Comment: You can use the REST interface to look up the JobId when you need it.

Comment: I have to know the jobID to use the API.  I can't filter jobs by name when searching the API.

Comment: `/joboverview/running` gives a list of all running jobs. You can filter that list for `name = yourName` to find the job you are looking for. Its not especially comfortable but should be doable like this.