# flink clients - set jobname when submitting job

Tags: apache-flink

I have a flink jar which I need to run on the flink cluster as a job, this job should be started from another java program. I am able to start the job using flink-clients library.

When I look into the flink job, I see the following code in `ExecutionEnvironment`

```
private static String getDefaultName() {
    return "Flink Java Job at " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}
```

This is my code to create the job

```
PackagedProgram packagedProgram = PackagedProgram.newBuilder()
      .setJarFile(new File(jarFilePath))
      .setArguments(args)
      .build();

JobGraph jobGraph = PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(packagedProgram, config, 2, true);
```

I would like to set the a custom jobName for the job. Can get help on setting the jobName?

Comment: You should be able to do it in JAR for the given job, do You have access to the source code for the job ??

Comment: @DominikWosiński yes, I have access to the source code of the jar and can make modifications to it.

The jar uses beam-flink-runner to run in flink.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Flink (How to uniquely tag Jobs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659290/apache-flink-how-to-uniquely-tag-jobs)

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann, no this doesn't answer my question, I am using ClusterClient to submit my jobs and I can't find method to specify jobName